# Управление положением элементов во flex-box при flex-direction: column

Tags: css

Есть HTML-блок, в котором мне нужно, чтобы: зелёный блок был по середине родительского блока, а красный - внизу. Но вот что-то `align-self` не работает. Какой существует способ расположить элементы в нужном мне порядке?

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.parent > div {
  display: block;
}
.parent > div.flex-start-node {
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-self: center;
}
.parent > div.flex-end-node {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="flex-start-node"></div>
  <div class="flex-end-node"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать `justify-content`. Проблема в том что при выставлении `flex-direction: column;` свойства переворачиваются и меняются местами т.е. `justify-content` стает `align-items` а `align-items` стает `justify-content`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}
.parent > div {
  display: block;
}
.parent > div.flex-start-node {
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-self: center;
}
.parent > div.flex-end-node {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="flex-start-node"></div>
  <div class="flex-end-node"></div>
</div>
```